# Xcode Not Deploying Phonegap App To 64bit Simulator Or Iphone 5s

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I have a phonegap project that deploys just fine on Iphone 5 running IOS 7 and older Phones to like Iphone 4. It also deploys to the 4 inch simulator just fine. However if i try to deploy on any 64 bit simulator or Iphone 5S which is a 64bit phone, the build fails and I dont know why.

The error it gives is as below.  "_CDVLocalNotification", referenced from:

```
  -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] in AppDelegate.o
```

"_CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification", referenced from:

```
  -[AppDelegate application:handleOpenURL:] in AppDelegate.o
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:

```
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:

```
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:

```
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVLogger in CDVLogger.o
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:

```
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
```

"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:

```
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
```

"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:

```
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
```

"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:

```
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVLogger in CDVLogger.o
```

"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:

```
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: It should give an error message..What is it?

Comment: @Harikrishnan Have a look i have edited and put the error logs

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Build Settings --> Architectures --> Valid Architectures`

Remove `arm64` from valid architectures section and try building.

[image]

Comment: @Hariskrishnan I have only one option which looks similar to the second one without the (including 64-bit) –